# Pattern to design generic Add,Edit,List screen

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am making generic master screen for LOV in WPF using Prism, MVVM, automapper etc for basic operation like add, edit, display, list.

There are three types of screens: 
1) List all data non editable.
2) Add, Edit, Delete, Display.
3) List all data editable (combination of 1 + 2).
All three approach have different Screens

Currently I have design 3 View Model:
1) ListViewModel
2) EditViewModel
3) ListEditViewModel
I have observe that the 3rd one is combination of 1st & 2nd.

What is the correct approach to develop these kind of screens ?

Comment: please give your valuable input...

Answer (score -1):

I think, it is better to create 2 different viewmodels (You can give another names for it):

1. EditViewModel
2. ListEditViewModel

And in second viewmodel create property like `IsEditable`(or `IsReadOnly`) and binding access for edit UI Controls using this property. It is in general way. 
In complex causes you can use some state enum of access roles insted of bool property for example:

- Forbidden
- ReadOnly
- CanEdit
- CanRemove

Comment: You can do this from a single viewmodel, and you shouldn't need any flags to indicate editability. Just have different views (or item templates) for each particular state or layout that is required.

Comment: Of course I can, but why I need to create 2 files for 2 similar views. I think for simple views better to create binding for "IsReadOnly" property of DataGrid (for example if it is some of list view) then duplicate xaml code for 2 or may be in future 3 similar views.
And the question was about viewmodels but not about views. So, it is on good create one viewmodel for "List" and "not List" models.

Comment: That first argument - creating two different files for 2 different views - is the same as what you were saying to do for the viewmodels - create a different VM for each state. The desired editability can be controlled purely by which view you choose. If you don't want multiple views then consider using data templates which can be manipulated based on what is being shown.

Comment: I think, you do not understand me correctly.
Ok, look at the question - We have had 3 types in viewmodels which author describe. I said that it is good way to create 2 kind of viewmodels based on model in it: 1) view model for individual entity 2) viewmodel for set of entities.That's all about viewmodels.
Then we need to organize user access based on access rules(there are 2 access rules in question - ReadOnly/Editable). You can organize it using different templates or views, I like another approach using binding and access property. Which approach is better depends on application UI design.

Comment: I understood perfectly what you were saying. You only need one VM no matter whether you have a single entity or multiple - the VM should have an IList<entities> so it handles both scenarios. You then have a readonly view, and an editable view. The two views can be one, and you can instantiate it with an appropriate constructor depending on what you want it to show as. Using the VM to signal that it is in edit mode reeks of code smell and moving UI related info into the VM.